# Rails 4 postgres full text search error (scoped)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, railscasts

Ive been following the railscast on full text search with postgres but I keep getting the following error

**undefined local variable or method `scoped' for #**

Ive followed the [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/343-full-text-search-in-postgresql?view=asciicast) exactly. I have all the correct gems installed. (pg_search, pg). Here is my code

article controller  (I'm also using acts_as_taggable here)

```
def index

   @articles = Article.text_search(params[:query]).page(params[:page]).per_page(3)

   if params[:tag]
      @articles = Article.tagged_with(params[:tag])
   else
      @articles = Article.all
   end
end
```

article model

```
def self.text_search(query)
  if query.present?
    where("name @@ :q or content @@ :q", q: query)
  else
   scoped
  end
end
```

And the form on Article/index

```
<%= form_tag articles_path, method: :get do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

The only difference I noted between the railscast code and mine is that hes using will_paginate but when I change the controller to

```
@articles = Article.text_search(params[:query])
```

it makes no difference.

Ive searched pretty much everywhere but to no avail.

Comment: Did not you got any *deprecated warning*. See this - http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/Association/scoped and  http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scoped

Comment: I suggest you use a debugging tool such as the `byebug` gem or the Rails `debugger` and stick them in both your `index` action and your `text_search` method.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`scoped` has been removed. Try `all` instead.

Comment: That gets rid of the error however when I put in a search I get all the articles. I'll mark this as accepted since it answers my question but any idea why searches are returning all?